Some questions on Hardy's spaces
In the paper http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1976__33_3_261_0.pdf, the authors have asked in Page 285 whether the Hardy space $H^p$ embeds isometrically into the Hardy space $H^q$ for  $1\leq q<p<2$? I want to know if this question is solved or not. Since I am not an expert on this, I am asking this question.

Why is this tagged with "banach-lattices"?

I hoped that maybe some more people would notice the question!

But it doesn't seem to be related to Banach lattices.

Have you tried the most (I might even say the only?) reasonable thing -- check all the papers that reference this paper and see what they say. Have you done that? I would assume not much more would be known, than what is already published.

@AlekseiKulikov There seem to be 3 papers citing this one, but no one seems to contain a solution to this problem.

Well, to me this seems to be an answer to your queston.
